# Receive Mail with node-red

Tags: email, node-red

Receiving mails with node-read is basically no problem thanx to the mail node.

My current problem is that I do not know how to avoid receiving the same mail twice when the server is restarted. One solution would be to delete every mail received, it I can't find a node for doing so.

Another problem which could arise is derived from the documentation - only the last mail is received. If, in a given intervall, several mails arrive, I guess only one of them will enter the flow - is tehre any solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround I currently use is to send another mail to the inbox after processing the first one. The second one is recognized as "status"-mail and will not be processed.